# How to authenticate 0auth in Jmeter for sharepoint app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jmeter-5.0

I have an app on SharePoint online and I have recorded a script for the home page which has a login form, after recording when I'm running the script it is showing failed for login auth as it creates dynamic client request id, when I run the script I think it creates different client_request_id that's why it is failing, I don't have prior experience of JMeter.